# Hiding behind proxy using Telethon/Socks5

Tags: python, proxy, telegram, telethon

When i sign in using these credentials and ip address, telegram on my cell phone detects my real ip. I tried closed issues on github telethon, the proxy server seems to be running fine since i ran nmap scan as well as pinged it using CLI

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

api_id = ''
api_hash = ''

with TelegramClient('Socheen', api_id, api_hash, proxy = {
    'proxy_type': 'socks5', 
    'addr': '208.102.51.6',      
    'port': 58208,
    'rdns': True
}) as client:
    client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!')
    client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different syntax for the proxy:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
import socks

api_id = ''
api_hash = ''

with TelegramClient('Socheen', api_id, api_hash, proxy = (socks.HTTP, 'x.x.x.x', 4444, True) as client:
    client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!')
    client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!'))
```

I haven't used Sock5 proxies but I've used HTTP/HTTPS proxies and they work fine.

```
(Proxy Type, IP, Port, rdns)
```

Comment: I certainly used this syntax (it was deprecated so i didn't mention it in my question), it didn't work

Comment: If it still does not work means there is something with telegram/telethon. Try the dev version of telethon if that does not work too then Sock5 will not. I use normal HTTP proxies and they work without a problem.